# Which preposition does the phrase "I can't guarantee" need to get?

Tags: prepositions

My classmate asked me today to tell him in what time we should be tomorrow in the collage, then I told him: "I think it should be on 9:00 o'clock but I can't guarantee (on/for) it."

Then I had a doubt: Which preposition does the phrase "I can't guarantee"  need to get in this case - if any?

> 1) "I can't guarantee **for** it.
>
> 2) I can't guarantee **on** it.
>
> 3) I can't guarantee it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't need a preposition, but the main clause might need a different one, depending on the context.

> I think it should be **on** 9 o'clock but I can't guarant**ee** it.

You don't need to write (or say) 9**:00** o'clock, it's redundant.

Also, *guarantee* is a verb in this case; my understanding is that *guaranty* may be used only when it is a noun. Here, you are saying that you cannot promise that it should be on 9 o'clock.

Try something like:

> I think by 9 o'clock, but I can't guarantee it.

The implication is that you are saying:

> I think [we should leave] by 9 o'clock, but I can't guarantee [that that is correct]

Comment: Also, the first bit is a bit awkward sounding - I would much prefer "I think we should leave by 9 o'clock but I can't guarantee that".

Comment: This is my fault for not reading the question thoroughly, one sec...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you actually say that it's not right to say "it should be...etc"? (and you recommended to me to use "we should have"?)

Comment: @Industrious you could say "it should be 9 o'clock..." in casual conversation, it would probably be acceptable, but it's not proper for formal communication.

Comment: @jimsug Thank you for the info. btw, why did you write "we should **leave**" when in fact we come to the college that time rather than leave?

Comment: @Industrious I suppose it depends on which time you mean (arrival or departure). Because you said go, I assumed you mean departure. But it works anyway.

Comment: Thanks to you I fixed it "My classmate asked me today to tell him in what time we **should be** tomorrow **in** the collage etc. (since we don't live together then we should not leave our houses in the same time)